# Where is the Workbench in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-experience, workbench, navigation

Where is the Workbench in Lightning Experience?

I am covering the [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_rest). The challenge there is to:

> Using REST API and Workbench, create an account with the name "Blackbeards Grog Emporium" and the description "The finest grog in the seven seas."

But I really do not know how to navigate to the Workbench from this:
[image]

Previously in the module I was able to follow the examples because the link to the Workbench was provided and actually I did not have to navigate to the Workbench myself.

At first it seems I have found the solution over [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_using_workbench.htm).

> Log in to your organization.
>   Open a new browser tab and navigate to `https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workbench`.
>   Log in to Workbench and allow access to your organization. Workbench is a public site and won’t retain your data.
>   Click Utilities | REST Explorer.
>   Ensure that Get is selected. The Execute text box is prepopulated with a portion of a resource path. Add the remaining information for your resource. For example, if your cURL syntax is
>   1
>   `https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/describe -H "Authorization: Bearer token"`
>   type
>   1
>   `/services/data/v32.0/sobjects/EventLogFile/describe`.
>   Click Execute.
>   Click Expand All or Show Raw Response to view your data.

But well, now I come to the point where I should: `Click Utilities | REST Explorer`.

But there is not `Click Utilities | REST Explorer` over here:
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workbench is an application which uses salesforce for authentication purpose and then perform operations on the data and metadata of the same salesforce org. It does not have anything to do with Lightning or classic experience as it works on its own.

You can reach to workbench with following link: https://workbench.developerforce.com/

[image]

After logging in with your org, you can see utility->rest explorer.

[image]